# Power BI with Azure Analysis Services

Tags: azure, powerbi

I'm about to jump in with Azure AS and I would appreciate some feedback. I understand that I will need to create the data model in AS - so, when having connected to the AS data model with Power BI desktop and created various measures, reports etc are they stored in Power BI are they pushed back to AS?

Would I be right in thinking that most if not all of the development could be done in BI Desktop without the need to create measures in AS? Many thanks, Martyn

Answer (score 2):

@Marten Hale. Just to let you know that there was an update in May, and yes, we can now add new measure from PowerBI Desktop Side when connected with Live Azure SSAS connection. You have to simply update the powerbi desktop.

Answer (score 1):

No. Currently all measure development needs to happen in Visual Studio SSDT (the BI Development tools). Currently it is not supported to add a measure in Power BI Desktop when connected live to Azure Analysis Services (or regular Analysis Services).

I will try to update this answer once this feature becomes available. **Edit: This feature is available now as noted by @Sambas23**

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. So it won't be possible to create any measures within the BI platform?

Comment: @MartynHale within Power BI Desktop, no

Comment: @MartynHale did that answer your question?